# Deleting closest div with modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm trying to delete an individual div after opening a modal window, at the moment I am stuck as I can't delete it.

The html is:

```
<h1>Delete individual image divs</h1>
<div class="image"><a href="#text">open delete modal</a>
</div>
<div class="image"><a href="#text">open delete modal</a>
</div>
<div class="image"><a href="#text">open delete modal</a>
</div>

<!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
<div class="lightbox" id="text">
<div class="box">
<a class="close" href="#">X</a>
<p class="title">Modal Window with Text</p>
<div class="content">
    <a class="delete" href="#delete">Delete</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('.image').remove();
return false;
});
```

Any help would be hugely welcomed.  I'm about to get a bald spot from this one.

A version of it can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/damianbuttle/hod6sk3r/1/

Comment: Probably you have provided an old fiddle. I cannot see JS code there.

Comment: I just updated it, please try again.

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the clicked `.delete` element. No `.image` is an ancestor of that element.

Comment: How would I connect the modal delete class with the class image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @showdev pointed out in his comment, $(this) has no connection with element which has to be deleted. You can add another handler for the clicked div:

```
var currentImage = null;
$('.image').click(function() {
    currentImage = $(this);
});
```

Then your remove should look e.g. like this:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    currentImage.remove();
});
```

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/hod6sk3r/7/

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to auto close the modal window after success?

Comment: Isn't it closed after action in my example? You can also execute click() manually.